# Permission denied from avgscan and when copying to folder from OS X

Tags: command-line

Two questions:

(1) I've just installed Ubuntu 10.04.2 on my Mac Pro and I've also installed clam and avg virus apps.  When I scan my home folder clamscan works fine but with avgscan ~/ I get "/home/ron  Object scan failed; Permission denied."

(2) I have a folder /media/Ubuntu_Data which I created in OS X. In Ubuntu I have a couple of files in my Download folder which I can't drag into this folder. I get "Error while copying to Ubuntu_Data. The destination is read only. I've tried chmod on this folder and I can't get it to work.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo mount`? Also that folder (`/media/Ubuntu_Data`) is in a different partition?

Comment: AFAIK, Apple's HPS+ support is read only in Linux. You have to disable journalling for write access.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) For this, it seems a simple `sudo avgscan ~` will suffice. If you are not familiar with `sudo`, try `man sudo`. It temporarily elevates the user to root privileges. `man` will fetch the manual page for a command. It is very useful to read these pages to understand how commands can be used and what they do.

(2) What exactly did you do with chmod? Remember the following: if using `chmod ###` the first number is for owner, the second for other users in the file's group, and the fourth for users not in the file's group.

Each number functions as follows:4 for read, 2 for write, and 1 for execution rights. So `chmod 777 /media/Ubuntu_Data` gives you everything. This isn't good practice unless you have a reason for it.

Also, `ls -l /media/Ubuntu_Data` will tell you the permissions currently set. At the end of the day, `chmod 775 /media/Ubuntu_Data` will give you write permissions on your folder without giving everyone in the world write. Give that a shot.

And please, for future question purposes, include as much info as you can, e.g. how you used the chmod command. "I've tried chmod on this folder and I can't get it to work." does not tell us a tremendous amount about what you did.

Comment: he's using HFS+ as a file system, that needs journalling turned off.
user138410: if you need additional info on HFS+ ask a new question.